# is there some tool to manage ssh port forward

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

Now I am using ssh port forward to access remote redis or other service through 22 port. When I want to connect redis on remote public domain server, I will open the ssh port forward in the terminal like this:

```
ssh -L 6479:127.0.0.1:6379 -N -f root@8.8.8.8
```

then I could using GUI tool connect to local 6479 port to access remote redis server. But every time I would run the ssh port forward in terminal and I have to remember the long command. Is there any tool to manage the port forward so I could open close the port or add remove the port forward easily? I found the `Mobaxterm` but it only works on windows, I am using macOS and Fedora.

Comment: *"I have to remember the long command"* why not keep it as alias/function? Or create a launcher for this.

Comment: ok, I already save it to my notepad, but I still have to copy and paste the command every time when I want to use port forward.@pLumo

Comment: Add it to .bashrc

Comment: seems a very simple way to solve this problem. @ArtemS.Tashkinov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to save those parameters to have a quick access is to add the connection details to `~/.ssh/config`. Something like this, based on the command line you provided:

```
Host myredis
    Hostname 8.8.8.8
    User root
    LocalForward 6479 127.0.0.1:6373
    SessionType none
```

You can then just run `ssh myredis`. You may add multiple hosts, and change details. Check `man ssh_config` for more details.